# Can anyone tell me how to Convert a Visual force page into an image using Apex

Tags: apex-email-service, apex

Is there any possibility to covert a VF page into an Image.?

[image: Report Using VF Page]

i've created a VF page Report, i need to schedule that **VF page Report** as like we schedule the **standard Reports** i want the email Body as like the image shown above. can anyone help me out of this would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

You say image, but a pdf use is often consistent with image use.

There is the standard renderAs capability, you should review the best practices for rendering a pdf as not all visualforce or html renders well: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="pdf">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you've already done the hard work of rendering the report output as a html table.  Perhaps consider a custom email with the report output embedded into the body, or maybe Im missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard mechanism to convert a Visualforce Page into an image. I agree to CloudHugger that the next best thing could be to embed the Page-HTML into an email body. You may face challenges with buttons, links and other controls.

If your recipients are salesforce users do all of them and yourself a favor and just send the link.